# Measuring relational inheritance distance between types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance, controls

Does anyone know how I could (or if there is an existing algorithm) measure the relational distance between two .NET types?

By this I mean the number of 'steps' in the hierarchical tree that is required to get from object A to object B.

For example, if object A is a Button, and object B is a LinkButton, there would be 2 steps, Button -> WebControl -> LinkButton. Would I need to create my own static inheritance tree and use a path finding algorithm, or is there a way I can dynamically look at the inheritance structure of .NET to calculate the distance between two objects?

Comment: Purely academic at the moment, I was looking to see if there was an existing algorithm for this measurement. Control looks like a good place to start, and then there are plenty of existing tree traversal methods to use. The Controls would only list existing objects though, what if my page did not have a Button, but I wanted to know the distance between an existing element (LinkButton) and a Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-generic way (also you don't have to specify parent/child explicitly):

```
private static int CalulateDistanceOneWay(Type firstType, Type secondType)
{
  var chain = new List<Type>();
  while (firstType != typeof(object))
  {
    chain.Add(firstType);
    firstType = firstType.BaseType;
  }

  return chain.IndexOf(secondType);
}

// returns -1 for invalid input, distance between types otherwise
public static int CalculateDistance(Type firstType, Type secondType)
{
  int result = CalulateDistanceOneWay(firstType, secondType);
  if (result >= 0)
  {
    return result;
  }

  return CalulateDistanceOneWay(secondType, firstType);
}
```

EDIT: update to calculate cousins:

```
public class DistanceResult
{
  public Type SharedAncestor { get; private set; }
  public int FirstTypeDistance { get; private set; }
  public int SecondTypeDistance { get; private set; }

  public DistanceResult(Type sharedAncestor, int firstTypeDistance, int secondTypeDistance)
  {
    SharedAncestor = sharedAncestor;
    FirstTypeDistance = firstTypeDistance;
    SecondTypeDistance = secondTypeDistance;
  }
}

static DistanceResult CalculateDistance(Type firstType, Type secondType)
{
  var firstChain = new List<Type>();
  while (firstType != typeof(object))
  {
    firstChain.Add(firstType);
    firstType = firstType.BaseType;
  }
  firstChain.Add(typeof(object));

  var secondChain = new List<Type>();
  while(secondType != typeof(object))
  {
    secondChain.Add(secondType);
    secondType = secondType.BaseType;
  }
  secondChain.Add(typeof(object));

  for(var i = 0; i < secondChain.Count; i++)
  {
    var type = secondChain[i];
    int index = firstChain.IndexOf(type);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
      return new DistanceResult(firstChain[index], index, i);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: This only goes "up" the hierarchy tree, so wouldn't allow me to find if A is a 'brother' or 'cousin' of B. Does a parent class have any knowledge of what other classes have inherited from it? I wouldn't think so...

Comment: The best way I can see is to walk up the tree of both objects and see where they intercept each other, then add the index of each list for a total distance. Thanks for your help, of you could extend your example to include that it would more in line with the original question. Unless you have another approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can walk through an inheritance path using `Type.BaseType`. For example:

```
 public static int GetTypeDistance<T, B>(T t, B baseType)
 {
        if (t is B) // checking if t inherits baseType
        {
            int distance = 0;
            Type curType = t.GetType();

            while (curType != typeof(B) && curType != null)
            {
                distance++;
                curType = curType.BaseType;                  
            }
            return distance;
        }
        else { throw new Exception("..."); }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers from Ondrej and Bényi here are two extension methods to compute the distance from a particular type to either its (indirect) base class type or one of the interfaces implemented by it or one of its base classes.

Usage examples:

```
Assert.AreEqual( 4, typeof( MultiDictionary<int, int> ).DistanceTo<IEnumerable>() );
Assert.AreEqual( 4, typeof( MultiDictionary<int, int> ).DistanceTo( typeof( IEnumerable ) );
Assert.AreEqual( 2, typeof( StringReader ).DistanceTo( typeof( IDisposable ) ) );
```

Extension methods:

```
public static class ExtensionsForType
{
    public static int DistanceTo( [CanBeNull] this Type current, [NotNull] Type target )
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>( target != null );

        // `root` will point to the topmost type which is implementing
        // our `target` interface
        Type root = current;

        // search for topmost base type implementing `target` interface type
        // or for the `target` base class type itself
        int distance = 0;
        while ( current != null && ( target.IsInterface
            ? current.GetInterfaces().Contains( target )
            : current != target ) )
        {
            root = current;
            current = current.BaseType;
            distance++;
        }

        // probably the `current` type does not even derive from / implement
        // the target type at all
        if ( current == null ) return -1;

        // if it's not an interface then we've found it in one of the base classes
        if ( !target.IsInterface ) return distance;

        // go one step back, because 'current' does not implement
        // our target interface anymore
        distance--;

        // iterate interface "derivations" while the target interface is still
        // in the list of implemented interfaces
        Type[] interfaces = root.GetInterfaces();
        while ( interfaces.Contains( target ) )
        {
            interfaces = interfaces.SelectMany( i => i.GetInterfaces() ).ToArray();
            distance++;
        }

        return distance;
    }

    public static int DistanceTo<T>( [CanBeNull] this Type current )
    {
        return current.DistanceTo( typeof( T ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: A practical use for this extension could be an algorithm searching for the best suited method or constructor for dependency injection.